# Community property settlement

Tags: real-estate

In a community property state , When one spouse dies and has left their half of a house to other persons; when must ownership of that half house be transferred ? Can ownership of half a house be transferred ?

Comment: Laws vary by state, which state are you interested in?  This may be better suited for https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ownership transfers on death. You are asking when you need to record it?

Comment: what ownership structure was involved: Tenants by the Entirety, Tenants in Common...

Comment: Thanks , I need to get more info. It is TX. Both names are on the title to a home , if that defines it.